# How to create 9patch from image with icon on one side

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'd like to 9patch this image, but I can't seem to

I've tried understanding the things mentioned here https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/articles/android-splash-screens-using-nine-patch-png but I can't seem to apply them to my image

Any ideas? And yes, it doesn't help that the icon is rounded ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the linked page you "draw lines that define the stretchable patches.". In your case, the stretchable part seems to be left of the logo until the left half-circle starts.

I added an image with an oversized stretch-line to mark the horizontally stretchable part.

[image: 9-patch with overemphazised stretch line]

Comment: In this case image with literal "f" will stretch on different device.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, to use your image only with 9 path. Best practices for your task - using several images with 9 path. Maybe creating custom view.

**1)**  As you can see, first image, parent with blue color, should include 9 path (it's easy to make without internal image).

**2)** For best looking in any device you need to create another thing for second image (with facebook char). 9 path for circle - not best idea. So I advice you use holder, with xml canvas background and char "f" in foreground.

**3)** Now you need to put this all in one FrameLayout, which you will use anywhere. All structure will be as example below:

```
<FrameLayout> // You may create custom view instead of FrameLayout
              // for more flexible and understanding 

   <BlueImageBackground.9path
    gravity=center>
   </BlueImageBackground.9path>

   <WhiteImageFacebokChar
    gravity= center_vertical | left>
   </WhiteImageFacebokChar>

</ FrameLayout>
```

As a result, in any screen, this image will appear identically...

Answer (score 0):

The source image you provided should be edited first, my version:

[image]

in sdk/tools folder there is draw9patch tool, so you can use it to edit it. You would see something like this:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it stretches the icon ... :(

Comment: @AndreiBogdan verticaly? there is link to 9-patch https://www.dropbox.com/s/9vrikr7t2evp7y8/nine-patch.9.png?dl=0 resource

Comment: yeah. vertically. if the text will be large (tall), won't it stretch the icon ? :(

Comment: that is the limitation of 9-patch, btw there is a way to fix that - use larger image for that, so you can find the perfect textSize/imageSize ratio. Or maybe you are using wrong resource folder, you should have this 9patch for each density

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is preferable to create an empty 9 patch image "without the logo" and then setting it as the background of a relative layout and then add an image view to the relative layout and add to the ImageView:

> android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>
> android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

Moreover you have to adjust the margin of the image view to achieve the desired result.

Note that this method will not stretch the icon & it requires some fine tuning to the image size and padding to achieve the desired results :-)